# Not able to call a webservice from node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to call a soap web service from node js. But the server does not show me any output either the success or the error. I am using http server for this purpose

My output is always :

[Thu Dec 15 2016 15:12:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] "GET /views/bookNGo.html?empId=EMP2&empName=ABCD&mobile=3312&alternateMobile=678&address=hjhjh&landMark=hjgjhgj&deptId=hjhj&projectId=hjgh&app
rovingManager=kjhkj&pickupPoint=jkhjkh&dropPoint=jkhjk" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"

```
var soap = require('soap');
console.log('One');
var url = 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/class/InsertEmployee?WSDL';
var args = {"employeeId": "EMP2","employeeName": "Chandra","phoneNumber":"12345","alternatePhoneNumber": "98765","address": "Boduppal",  "landMark": "Temple","departmentID": "001","projectID": "001","approvingManager": "Prashanth","pikupPoint": "Uppal","dropPoint":"Hitec"};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
client.createEmployee(args, function(err, result) {

      console.log("Webservice called");
      console.log(result);
  });
});
```

I have tired running the code in https://runkit.com/npm/soap and it gives me an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'InsertEmployeeService' of undefined".

Comment: Try without the ?WSDL part of the url. You don't want to generate the WSDL, you want to invoke the webservice.

Comment: Tried it but the same error is coming up and based on some other questions and comments changed the below code
    
client.InsertEmployeeService.InsertEmployeeBinding.createEmployee(args, function(err, result)

But still facing the same error